# JS remove array variable names

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, list

I'm new in JS... can someone help me to change this:

```js
arr = [{type:'fruit', name:'apple', color:'red'},{type:'fruit', name:'banana', color:'yellow'}]
```

to this:

```js
arr = [['fruit', 'apple', 'red'],['fruit', 'banana', 'yellow']]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map your array using `Object.values()` as a callback:

```js
arr = arr.map(Object.values);
```